# Vue.js prop not being rendered in child component

Tags: vuejs2

I have two components, Login.vue and Home.vue. I need to pass a variable from Login to Home using props.

So, in my parent, Login.vue i use

```
<template>
  <b-nav-form @submit.prevent="login">
      <home :error='error'></home>
      ...
  </b-nav-form>
</template>
```

and

```
<script>
import Home from './Home'
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  components: {
    home: Home
  },
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
        // not interesting
    },
    loginSuccessful (req) {
      //not interesting too
    },
    loginFailed (req) {

      this.error = 'LOGIN ERROR'

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to send `error` to Home

so in Home.vue

```
<template>
     <header class="container-home">
<div class="container h-100">
    <span>This is the HOME</span>
    <span> {{error}}</span>
</div>
     </header>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  props: ['error']
}

</script>
```

`error` is rendered in Login.vue but no `error` in Home.vue

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Check the section on prop casing.

You are using camelCase in the template prop name. Since HTML is case insensitive you need to use kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalent instead.

```
<home :error-message="error"></home>
```

Comment: thanks but this is not the problem... i changed my errorMessage to simply error (updated the question) but nothing changes

Comment: @besmart then provide a https://codesandbox.io/ with your problem so we can help better.